# LUKS partition much larger than filesystem (LVM)

Tags: partitioning, luks

I recently installed Ubuntu on a laptop with 256 GB SSD. I chose the recommended layout (use entire disk) and selected LUKS, but although the installer created a sufficiently large partition –

```
jan:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                        8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                        8:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                        8:3    0 235.4G  0 part  
  └─dm_crypt-0              253:0    0 235.4G  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0   100G  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                       /
```

– the LVM size is only 100G:

```
jan:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              781M  2.2M  779M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   26G   68G  28% /
tmpfs                              3.9G   28K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  134M  1.7G   8% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              781M  2.4M  779M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Why is the ubuntu volume much smaller than possible, and can I safely use resize2fs to use the remaining space in the sda3 partition?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: You med to resize the lvm volume then you can resize the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Anders, I followed [these instructions](https://slice2.com/2020/12/05/howto-easily-resize-the-default-lvm-volume-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to resize the LVM volume and then the filesystem:

```
sudo lvresize -t -v -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv # with test flag (-t)
sudo lvresize -v -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv # remove -t after successful test
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```